# Modifying ArcGIS Network Analyst route when route created is flawed?

Tags: distance, network-analyst, routing, arcgis-10.4, network

I'm analyzing an optimized routes for garbage collection. There are roughly 250 orders per route. I've ran the Network Analyst tool both with time and length impedances. In both cases, the output solution will indicate the route will 'drive' past an order without stopping. I'm looking to figure out how to correct this in my analysis but without having to closely examine each of the 1,000 pickup points.

I'm using the Route tool, partially because when I do a Fleet Analysis, the problem still exists, but GIS takes longer to solve. Impedance is set to Minutes, I've checked Reorder Stops to Find Optimal Route, as well as preserve First and Last Stop. U-Turns are allowed only at Dead Ends.

The attached graphic is the first example I could find. The route travels from 28 to 29, passing 40 in the process.[image: Routing Example]

Comment: Are you using any side of street restrictions? If you are and pickup is on opposite side of street as travel, it won't stop, it will come back the other direction. UPS uses this kind of restriction to avoid left-hand turns, which generally cost more time and have more risk than right-hand turns. In fact some places do this for all routing, not just stops (avoid left turns).

Comment: Yes, I am using side of street restrictions that specify the stop must be on the right hand side but unfortunately the route is passing stops on the proper side for collection.

Comment: Hrm... I know I've run into this before, some exercise I was doing with garbage trucks, but I can't for the life of me remember what the problem ended up being and I've been away from networks for a while. I'll see if I can find it. Is it skipping isolated stops due to time constraints? You could improve your question (and bump it) by adding a screenshot showing an example, indicating which specific network solver you're using, and potentially adding some detail as far as how you've configured said solver (allowing u turns? allowing stops to be reordered?).

Comment: I've added a graphic, as well as some description to my analysis. I had tried using the Vehicle Routing tool, but I was having the same problem. In an effort to resolve the problem, I was using the Route tool to determine a route, then using the sequence when I ran the Vehicle Routing.